# React Native - How to make horizontal FlatList repeat from start when reaching end

Tags: reactjs, list, react-native, horizontal-scrolling, flatlist

I'm trying to make horizontal list and when scrolled to end it should start from start game (like A B C D E and when E is reached it should show A next). Is there any way to implement this or to achieve this? I found this [library](https://github.com/prateek3255/react-native-infinite-looping-scroll) but it's not working on horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

There is a prop named onEndReached you could set the state again when the list goes to the end.